# how to get a tolerance for mouseOver behaviour in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseover, hittest

i'm making an application that draws curves with as3 and i ant the curves to highlight when the mouse is over.

I managed to do it with mouseOver, but the interaction is not natural because you have to be exactly on the curve (1px wide) to highlight it. So i was wondering if it was possible to have some sort of 'tolerance' on the mouseOver behaviour.

I know i could use a enterFrame event and check there the distance between the curve and the cursor, but it seems to me it will be a lot of calculations for such a simple task.

thanks.

ps: my curves are not real curves (like bezier), but a succession of lineTo commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no tolerance in mouse_over, so the quickest solution that I can imagine is to draw thicker line with alpha set to 0, and then addEventListener to that thicker invisible line.

Comment: ok thanks... but i thought if alpha was set to zero, mouseEvents did not fire?

Comment: it doesn't matter, alpha only means that you can't see that object, while it is on stage and fully functional.